# CSS - Cannot change placeholder color by class

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a project where the placeholder color was defined globally by developer. But now I need to style a form with a different placeholder color. How can I address it correctly?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyDns/1/)

CSS

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
color: red;

}
::-moz-placeholder {
color: red;

}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: red;

}


.box input::-webkit-input-placeholder, .box textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
.box input:-moz-placeholder, .box textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
.box input:-ms-input-placeholder, .box textarea:-ms-input-placeholder{
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: `.box::-webkit-input-placeholder` etc. - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyDns/2/)

Comment: So you picked the answer that had no explanation at all and they most likely copied it from Vucko. Because that makes so much sense, don't give it to one of the people that put time and effort into explaining what was wrong with it and how to fix it.

Comment: I agree cent percent with @Ruddy **Value Addition:** Just in case someone was wondering why Vucko's suggestion works but not OP's, its because OP's CSS will look for `input` and `textarea` inside `.box`. Alternatively, `input.box` and `textarea.box` should also work which targets class by element type...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/vyDns/3/

you where close only needed to add .box in front like:

```
 .box::-moz-placeholder
```

Cheers

Comment: Care to explain why only `.box` was needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your target in several solutions.

In the first one, you should change your HTML markup. With your CSS, you first search for the class "box", and the for the input element. So the working HTML markup would be:

```
<span class="box"><input /></span>
```

While the span element could be any other element, it should just have the box as class.
[Demo 1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rimAx)

---

The second solution is to write the input (and also textarea) in your CSS in front of the `.box` element. So you call only input and textarea elements which have the "box" class.

```
input.box::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea.box::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

[Demo 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/duoeG)

---

The last solution is to delete the input and the textarea part. So you'll call all elements, which have "box" as a class.

```
.box::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

[Demo 3](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fbicy)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because I think the other answer by Filip Huysmans was just copied from Vucko's comment. I am going to also answer it and explain why your code didn't work.

**Lets use this one as an example:**

```
.box input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

Here you are selecting `.box` and then trying to find an `input` to change the placeholder colour. If your code was like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <input placeholder="blue" />
</div>
```

It would have worked. In the code above you are selecting the class `.box` and then finding all `inputs` within it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/vyDns/4/)

---

Now in your code we have:

```
<input class="box" placeholder="blue" />
```

So you are already in the `input`, thats why your code didnt work. There is no `input` in the `input`. So taking away `input` from the CSS and leaving just `.box` means you are selecting just that `input`.

```
.box::-webkit-input-placeholder
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/vyDns/8/)

Hope this explains it well enough for you to understand where you went wrong.

Comment: What's with the negative attitude? I did not copy anything just made it work for his needs..

Comment: @FilipHuysmans With no explanation, on something like this a simple line about why it was wrong would help a lot of other people and not just the OP. Look at mine and dTDesign answers, that's going to help a few more people then just the OP. Don't get me wrong your answer is correct and if you say you did it yourself then that's fair enough but next time I recommend putting some effort into the answer so other users / viewers can benefit from it as well. Also nice downvote there because you don't like what I said. Good job.

Comment: No problem, that's what you get when you criticize people. I'll try to give more explanations next time in order to help others.

Comment: @FilipHuysmans: You shouldn't downvote an answer because someone criticize you. Ruddy's answer should get an upvote, because his answer is useful (hover the up-/ downvote buttons to see when you shuld click them). And try to learn from critics. So I learn how to answer on SO too. My first answers were horrible, but I tried to make it better. Your answer could be useful becuase it works, but an answer should always have an explanation. Add an explanation to your answer, and your answer will be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: white;
opacity: 1;
```

Just add it in the input/text area tag directly

eg. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqgOOp